# iOS application base path

Tags: ios, cordova, backbone.js, jekyll

I am currently developing an application using Phonegap / Jekyll / Backbone. I am however in the need for a base path for my generation of static content. For Android platforms I use `/android_asset/www/` which is working fine. I am however unable to find one for iOS, anyone has any idea about it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two main locations in iOS device are NSDocumentDirectory and NSApplicationDirectory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to asynchronously ask the iOS device to give you the root path. In *deviceready* function call:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFS, null);
```

When ready it will callback with a *FileSystem* object from which you can access the full root path.

```
function onFS(fs) {
    alert(fs.root.fullPath); 
}
```

Read more on PhoneGap/Cordova docs: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileSystem